# Is it possible for a Firefox WebExtension to uninstall itself prior to Firefox version 51?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, uninstallation, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible to uninstall *my own* Firefox WebExtension (not based on the Add-on SDK) **programmatically** in Firefox versions prior to 51 where the `management.uninstallSelf` API method [will be available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management/uninstallSelf#Browser_compatibility)?

Comment: `uninstallSelf` is only to unistall addons of your own.

Comment: That would be a huge security hole.

Comment: Correct, I need to find a way to uninstall my own web-extension and I'm not sure why so many minuses.

Comment: I don't get significant downvotes on this question, frankly.

Comment: @dajnz it was probably down-voted because initially it missed "my own" :)  I up-voted to compensate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no.

Extensions are sandboxed enough that they cannot interact with management functions with the exception of `management` API.

If that wasn't implemented in WebExtensions until FF 51, you're out of luck. The most you can do is to invoke `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage` (supported since FF 48) to present the user with the UI that explicitly has the "Remove" button.

Comment: Ok, this could be a sort of temporary workaround for me, thank you!